# function pointers in c++ : error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Code snippet is as follows. Not able to understand why I am getting this error.

```
void
SipObj::check_each_field()
{
  map <std::string, sip_field_getter>::iterator msg;
  string str;
  char name[20];
  bool res = false;
  sscanf(get_payload(), "%s %*s", name);
  LOGINFO(lc()) <<  "INVITE:" << name;
  str = name;
  msg = sip_field_map.find(str);
  if (msg != sip_field_map.end()) {
      sip_field_getter sip_field = msg->second;
      res = (this).*sip_field();
  }
}

 typedef bool (SipObj::*sip_field_getter)();
 static map <std::string, sip_field_getter> sip_field_map;
```

`sip_field_getter` is a place holder for function names

Comment: Does it work with `this->sip_field()` (AKA `(*this).sip_field()`)?

Comment: @chris: You seem to be really helpful, but always work with comments instead of answers... Care to provide an answer that explains why `this.` is wrong? People are discouraged to write as an answer what already is present in a comment... feels somewhat like cheating ;)

Comment: @K-ballo Sometimes you just want to solve the problem for someone, not write a complete answer. As soon as you start writing an answer, you're expected to go into depth and be sure you're 100% correct.

Comment: @K-ballo, I wasn't exactly sure if it was that or if a pointer-to-member was actually needed, either. I wasn't too inclined to go looking through to figure out which one was right.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
(this).*sip_field();
```

There are two problems with this expression:

1. `this` is a pointer, so you must use `->*` to call a member function via pointer on it.
2. the function call (`()`) has higher precedence than the member-by-pointer operators (either `.*` or `->*`), so you need parentheses to correctly group the expression.

The correct expression is:

```
(this->*sip_field)();
```

Comment: I never understood why `.*` and `->*` don't have the same precedence as `.` and `->` (and function calls) ...

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you're calling a method pointer on a pointer, but you're calling it with the dot-star syntax.  Try replacing

```
res = (this).*sip_field();
```

with

```
res = (this->*sip_field)();
```

Comment: Another option would be (*this.*sip_field)(), though I think that's a little messier in my opinion.

Comment: you would need an extra set of parenthesis around `*this`... so yes, a bit messier and error prone

Answer (score 6):

The correct syntax is this:

```
(this->*sip_field)();
```

Or if you want to use `.` instead of `->`, then this:

```
((*this).*sip_field)();
```

I would prefer the former syntax.